# How to open any link in other window

Tags: html

Following line of code opens a same page,How can I make it open in other new window??

```
string str="<td><a href='#' onclick='GoToFunction()'>" + dataTable.Rows[i][j] + "</a></td>"
```

Plz Reply...I don`t know why html tags are not displaying

Comment: add target="_blank" for <a> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are running a javascript function `onclick` you'll need to use javascript to open a new window. Simply adding `target="_blank"` as you would to a standard `a` element won't work. Try this:

```
function GoToOrchestra() {
    // your code...

    var win = window.open("http://myurl.com", "newWindow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `<a>` tag, simply add [a target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) set to "_blank".

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">My Link</a>
```

Comment: :wat actually a target means??

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Does that help?